# How to compute exponent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I wonder if it is possible to compose formulas by hand like: $1+2+3+\cdots+n$. The formula for this is:$(n)(n+1)/2$.

And for $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2+\cdots+n^2$ you have the formula: ...

But this is more a trial and error work. So my question is, is it possible too generate series of the form: $1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3$ or $1^4+2^4+3^4+\cdots+n^4$, etc. by logic and not by trial and error?

Thank you

Comment: Refer to Faulhaber's formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2+\cdots+n^2$ is not by trial and error. There is a proof by logic, which is as follows.

Note $$(n+1)^3-1^3=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^3-k^3=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(3k^2+3k+1)$$
$$=3\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2+3\sum_{k=1}^{n} k+\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1$$

This gives us that $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6}$$
We can do something similar for $n^3$, $n^4$, and there is a formuala for the $p$-th powers called [Faulhaber's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: Ah, thank you. Very nice

Comment: @NIelsSavant Out of curiosity, was this not in your book? This proof is mentioned in the second page of my high school textbook on sums.

Comment: No. Realy I studied by myself programming and physics. And ofcourse I learned sums and series. But I never heard about a general formula to compute a serie of the n-th power